# Index was outside the bounds of the array in my case

Tags: c#

Why the index in my case goes beyond the boundaries of the array, I still can't understand?
Complete the method/function so that it converts dash/underscore delimited words into camel casing. The first word within the output should be capitalized only if the original word was capitalized (known as Upper Camel Case, also often referred to as Pascal case).

```
using System;
using System.Text;
public class Kata
{
    public static string ToCamelCase(string str)
    {
        string[] res=str.Split(new char[]{'-','_'},System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(res[0]);
        for(int i=1;i<res.Length;i++){
            char[] ch=res[i].ToCharArray();
            ch[0]=Char.ToUpper(ch[0]);
            sb.Append(new string(ch));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the input that failed?

Comment: Just some friendly advice: if you indent your code properly, it becomes far easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm offering two solutions. The first formats the input as Pascal Case.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ToCamelCase("camels-drink-LOTS-OF_WATER"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string ToCamelCase(string str)
{
    // This holds our output
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Step 1 - split input into array of words
    string[] res = str.Split(new char[] { '-', '_' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            
    // Step 2 - loop through the array
    for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
    {
        // For each word,
        // change all of the letters to lowercase
        res[i] = res[i].ToLower();

        // Then change the first letter to uppercase
        char[] ch = res[i].ToCharArray();
        ch[0] = Char.ToUpper(ch[0]);

        // Finally, add the result to our output
        string c = new string(ch);
        sb.Append(c);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The second formats as Camel Case - it contains additional logic to handle the first word in your input array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ToCamelCase("camels-drink-LOTS-OF_WATER"));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string ToCamelCase(string str)
{
    // This holds our output
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Step 1 - split input into array of words
    string[] res = str.Split(new char[] { '-', '_' }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        
    // Step 2 - loop through the array
    for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
    {
        // For each word,
        // change all of the letters to lowercase
        res[i] = res[i].ToLower();

        // Then change the first letter to uppercase unless it's the first word
        char[] ch = res[i].ToCharArray();                

        if (i != 0)
        {
            ch[0] = Char.ToUpper(ch[0]);
        }

        // Finally, add the result to our output
        string c = new string(ch);
        sb.Append(c);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Let me know in the comments if you need any more help.

If this answer helps you, please click the gray checkmark to the left. This marks the question as solved and gives me some "rep" which is used to access features on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Nevertheless thank you.
The problem was related to the StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries enumeration, in my case it was possible to remove it and the tests would pass successfully.
The tests check some string, but this method reduces its length by removing whitespaces

Comment: Thanks! Btw what input string did you use?

Answer (score 2):

@Evgeny20 First, you should do your own homework. Second, debuggers are your friend, whatever environment they have you using for your CS homework figure out the debugger so you can step through it.  This type of thing becomes easy then.

I'll provide a solution that's using .net core 3.1.  If you're using old framework you'll need to modify it to not use Spans and instead use string functions.  Don't use the char array.

If you get array index out of bound issues with this - using the forced upper case - then then put in a test for the string to make sure it's non-null and non-empty.  But I don't think you will...

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string S1 = "camel-Case_this-String";
        const string Check = "camelCaseThisString";

        var result = ToCamelCase(S1);

        if (result != Check)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public static string ToCamelCase(string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return str;

        string[] tokens = str.Split(new char[] { '-', '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (tokens.Length == 0)
            return str;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length);

        sb.Append(tokens.First());

        foreach (var token in tokens.Skip(1))
        {
            sb.Append(char.ToUpper(token[0]));
            if (token.Length > 1)
            {
                sb.Append(token.AsSpan().Slice(1));
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```